# Review code in Accurev using crucible

Tags: svn, accurev, atlassian-crucible

I have earlier used Crucible to setup code review for the code lying in SVN. I remember there used to be feature either to select difference between two version of files, or I was able to select whole file. I always found selecting whole file better as it gave view of the whole code and I used to get committer name and version against each line on Crucible GUI, to get an idea what has been committed recently on a file.

Now I am to setup review of the code which is present in Accurev. If I select whole files (instead of only difference), I donot get to see this history information on the file being reviewed. So the reviewer doesn't have an idea which part of file is recently updated and hence is to be reviewed. Or the other option is to select difference only, which is not so user friendly on Crucible UI to be reviewed.

Am I missing some option on crucible while creating review or is this a limitation of accurev?

Comment: We are planing to setup Crucible to work with Accurev/Jira setup. I'm very interested in this question myself.

Answer (score 0):

In AccuRev Web Interface, if you choose "Add to Review", you will get a diff from the last review.